# Casting Single Case discriminated union to int in F#?

Tags: .net, optimization, f#

I am working on a chess engine written in F#, and I'm thinking of how to represent the board positions.

The board data structure is an array of 64 elements. Since there are only 64 possible indices, I'm thinking of just restricting it as a single case discriminated union instead of just a regular int `[<Struct>]type BoardPosition = Position of int`
this would help me reason better, and probably reduces the number of tests.

How would I use this `Position` type to index an array? I tried testing casting it to explictly (`(int) data`) but that doesn't seem to work

Is my approach ideal? Is there some major overhead with using a discriminated union and I should just stick to using a regular int?

Comment: You should remove the `c#` tag from this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've wrapped the index in a new type, you have to unwrap the type in order to access the raw index. You can do this with pattern matching:

```ml
let get (Position idx) (board : _[]) =
    board[idx]
```

Simple usage example:

```ml
let board = [| "king"; "queen"; "pawn" |]
let pos = Position 1
get pos board
    |> printfn "%A"   // "queen"
```

There is some performance and cognitive overhead here, so you'll have to decide if it's worthwhile. In general, this topic is called "[primitive obsession](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/)".

Comment: thanks. didn't realize it was that easy. I guess I'll have to benchmark to see if the extra cost is worth it

Comment: Another possibility to achieve some better type safety is to use units of measure, which does not have any extra processing cost. In any case it's rare that we use anything but plain ints for indexing, so personally I'd never bother in a use case like your's here.

Answer (score 2):

Using an array to represent the board is definitely an option - but if you want to write the chess engine in a functional way using immutable data structures, it may not lead to the nicest code.

I would consider representing the board using `Map` that assings pieces to positions. The nice thing about this is that it makes it very easy to create a copy of the board with one position changed (so that you can e.g., simulate various moves).

I'm mainly thinking about how easy it is to write code - efficiency is another concern (but perhpas one worth worrying about later). I'd start with something like:

```
type Position = byte * byte

type Piece = 
  | Pawn
  | King
  | Queen

type Color = 
  | Black
  | White

type Board = Map<Position, Color * Piece>

let sampleMove (board:Board) = 
  if board.TryFind(3uy, 1uy) = Some(White, Pawn) then
    board.Remove((3uy, 1uy)).Add((3uy, 2uy), (White, Pawn))
  else board
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't give proper context
I'm actually not using an array for the representation, I'm using bitboards - a 64 bit number that maps to all locations.
The array is a lookup table, with it you can pregenerate to make getting attacks(represented as bitboards) for piece faster. 
The lookup has 64 bitboards, indexing gives you the bitboard for that location. 
I wanted to restrict it to the `Position` type since there are only 64 indices. Others have pointed out that I could use pattern matching or units of measure, so I'll test that out
Thanks for the comment. though

Answer (score 1):

A zero-overhead way to attach metadata to primitives like `int` is with [Units of Measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure)

```fs
type ArrayWithMeasure<'T, [<Measure>] 'M>(arr: 'T[]) =
    member _.Item(i: int<'M>) = 
        arr[int i]

[<Measure>]
type position

type Piece = 
| Pawn
| King
| Queen

let board = ArrayWithMeasure<Piece option, position>(Array.create 64 None)

let pos = 1<position>

board[pos]
```

The above shows how you can create a measure-safe wrapper around an array and access it.